# Javascript Fetch Function returns [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, html, django, fetch-api

I'm currently working on a project, which includes a website, built and run by Django. On this website, I'm trying to load data through fast API and try to load this data through JavaScript and the Fetch API. But I always get instead of the Data provided through the API, an [object Promise]. I've tried many different methods but none seem to work.

I've tried for example:

```
document.getElementById("1.1").innerHTML = fetch('the URL')
 .then(response => response.text())
```

or

```
document.getElementById("1.1").innerHTML = fetch('the URL')
.then(response => response.text())
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

and many other methods. I've also checked and the API request works perfectly, returning a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the setting of the html to appear when you log the final response, eg:

```
fetch('the URL')
.then(response => response.text())
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    document.getElementById("1.1").innerHTML = response
})
```

Other ways including making the whole of the response promise to be fulfilled:

```
const getData = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url)
  const resText = await res.text()
  return resText
}
const addTextFromUrl = async (url, element) => {
  const text = await getData(url)
  element.innerHtml = text
}
addTextFromUrl('theUrl', document.getElementById("1.1"))
```

Generally it is a little easier to follow the async/await syntax when learning, but you should always try/catch any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Every `.then` call does return a new promise. So

You need to assign value in a callback or use `async/await`

```
fetch('the URL')
.then(response => response.text())
.then((response) => {
    document.getElementById("1.1").innerHTML = response
})
```

or do it inside an async function

```
async function getHtml() {
  document.getElementById("1.1").innerHTML = await fetch('the URL')
   .then(response => response.text())
}

getHtml();
```

W/o using `then`

```
async function getHtml() {
  const response = await fetch('the URL');

  const html - await response.text();

  document.getElementById("1.1").innerHTML = html;
}

getHtml();
```

Comment: Somehow if I try this, then it does indeed not return [object Promise], but instead a blank. I've checked the URL and it looks fine, returning a string. Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Levi.mbc Make sure `document.getElementById("1.1")` is returning anything it might be that you are just getting an error.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I looked inside the console and found out that it is now returning an error related to access control.

Comment: @Levi.mbc It could be that `const html - await response.text()` should be `const html = response.text()`

Comment: @tlietz You need await on it. Otherwise you'd get Promise<string>. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text